# How to run sibling Go applications (modules) from the parent directory

Tags: go, go-modules

I have multiple Go projects (and all of them are also [Go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules)) all in a folder. They are all HTTP servers and exchanging REST calls, thus, I need all of them up and running simultaneously.

So, for local testing purposes, I thought it would be reasonable to run all of them from the parent instead of moving all of the project root directories and running `go run main.go` in multiple terminals.

```
container_dir/
├── prj1/
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── main.go
│   └── ...
├── prj2/
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── main.go
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

Here are some some commands I have tried and the error messages for each time:

```
container_dir $ go run ./*/*.go
##ERROR: named files must all be in one directory; have ./prj1/ and ./prj2/
```

```
container_dir $ go run *.go
##ERROR: stat *.go: no such file or directory
```

```
container_dir $ go run ./prj1 ./prj2/
##ERROR: cannot find package "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4" in any of:
           /usr/local/go/src/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4 (from $GOROOT)
           /home/user/go/src/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4 (from $GOPATH)
         cannot find package ...
```

So, I can give a final rephase for the question: **How to run multiple go modules in sibling directories when they have some third party dependencies etc.?**

P.S: As possible with Go modules suggest `container_dir` for my projects is in an arbitrary location and I expect no `$GOPATH` relevance.

Go version: 1.13.6

Comment: `go run` launches a single go app, not multiple.

Comment: Ok, nice info. But still I cannot find a way even with separate `go run` calls without changing directory like `cd prj1` etc.

Comment: `go run prj1/main.go` should launch the first app–given its main package consists of this single file. `go run prj2/main.go` should launch the other app.

Comment: I am nit sure. It results in the app cannot find dependencies indeed like `cannot find package "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"` so on. However, when I do `go run main.go` in `prj1` directory, it runs.

Comment: What is wrong with `go build whatever && ./whatever` ? You are deliberately making your life complicated.

Comment: Would something like `ls -F | grep "/" | xargs -I % bash -c "go run %*.go"` work? (assuming you're using a bash shell and want to run them sequentially)

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't use `go run` outside of tiny, playground-style tests
2. Source paths are a compile-time concern and are irrelevant at runtime - being in "sibling directories" doesn't mean anything when the program is running
3. `go run` runs a single program; just like building a program and running its executable binary (which is what `go run` does) runs a single program.

Comment: Indeed I am not telling using a single `go run` for multiple apps is a must for my case. I was only brainstorming for running multiple apps at once without traversing through directories.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your go.mod stuff is having problems dude.

remember you can do replace inside it and reference your other application

```
module container_dir/prj2

go 1.13

require(
container_dir/prj1 v0.0.0
)

replace (
container_dir/prj1 => ../prj1
)
```

require is the path you import but it'll get switched to the relative path on build.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but a module does not import from another. They are self-sufficient for compile-time.